# DocuSign API - Is there a way retrieve documents from multiple envelopes as zip file with one API call?

Tags: docusignapi

We have a requirement to download documents from multiple envelopes, as zip file, with one click.

Is there an API method to achieve the same?

If not, any recommendations?

Didn't see an option to try yet.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot do this, you have to do one envelope at a time.
An envelope can be zipped even if you have many files.
But you cannot zip multiple envelopes with one API calls.

You can go to https://feedback.docusign.com and ask for a feature request.